# How to give away money in GTA V Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I just got GTA yesterday, and I held up a store. When I came outside someone gave me a ride away. Is there a way for me to pay him for helping me?

Comment: There's an option in the context menu which is something along the lines of "Share cash from last job". I'm sure you'll get a more detailed answer soon.

Answer (score 5):

Go to the interaction menu (M), select Inventory -> Cash -> Share Cash from Last Job. There you can see how much you earnt and which percentage you want to give to any other online players in your session.

Comment: That works for jobs and missions - but does it work for stealing from a gas station in free mode?

Comment: For robbing stores at gas stations in freemode, yes, it definitely works.

Answer (score 0):

There is a different way but it requires a lot of money, more than you're gonna share:

Go to LS Customs pick a car there and tune it. DON'T place insurance on it. Then, go to sell the car to see how much its worth, don't sell it, go to the closest mission, join the mission with your friend and leave (you have to host). The car will then spawn on you again so your friend can take it and sell it.